# Organize responsive images on desktop and mobile layouts

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align two images side by side - pair after pair down by landing page on wide screen and single image - one after another on mobile screen layout:

```
<div  class="container">
    <div class="set">
      <div class="column">
        <img src="" id="img3" class="images">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="" id="img4" class="images">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="" id="img5" class="images">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="" id="img6" class="images">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

`container`  css:

```
  .container { 
      height: relative; 
      padding: 0px 12px;
      margin-top:0px;
      margin-bottom:0px;
      border-radius: 0px;
      background-color: transparent; 
    }
```

`set` and `column` css:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.set {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  flex: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

`images` css:

```
 .images {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      padding: 23px;
    }
```

Actual result is a scalable images in one line with both screen layouts, left is a wide screen, right is mobile:

[image]

but I'm trying to get this result:

[image]

Comment: Try using media queries

Comment: media query or you can use bootstrap.

Comment: You should use `flex-wrap` in css, so that the elements wrap, when there is no space anymore

Comment: @klediooo but then you need to increase the width of the column class when in mobile view in order to get the required result.

Comment: @klediooo  Hello, then I use  display: flex;  flex-wrap: wrap;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to give one more parameter in your css file

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
     .set{display:block}
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late replay, this is  useful